# Add count inside MongoDB aggregation

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, mongoose

How to add count inside MongoDB aggregation. In this aggregation I'm sorting data by deep nested field "category". Catalog product is an ObjectId of catalog product. Inside catalog product I have an ObjectId of category.

```js
products = await StorageModel.aggregate([
                { $lookup: {  // Replace the Catelog Product ID with the Catelog Product
                        from: "catalogs",
                        localField: "catalogProduct",
                        foreignField: "_id",
                        as: "catalogs"
                    } },
                { $lookup: {  // Replace the Category ID with the Category
                        from: "categories",
                        localField: "catalogs.category",
                        foreignField: "_id",
                        as: "catalogs.category"
                    } },
                { $addFields: {  // Replace the Category with its name
                        "catalogs.category": "$catalogs.category"
                    } },
                { $match: {
                        "catalogs.category._id": { $in: ids }
                    } },
                { $lookup: {  // Replace the Catelog Product ID with the Catelog Product
                        from: "catalogs",
                        localField: "catalogProduct",
                        foreignField: "_id",
                        as: "catalogProductNew"
                    } },
                { $count: "count" },
                { $sort: { _id: -1 } },
                { $skip: (page - 1) * 8 },
                { $limit: 8 },
            ]);
```

Returns. But another data from aggregation was erased.

```js
[ { count: 3 } ]
```

Comment: Would be helpful if you can provide some sample dataset and expected output.

Comment: I think you have done a great job of figuring out the solution of using `$facet` on your newer question. So I suggest to mark the question as duplicate of your newer question as the solution is already there.